# Entity reference field changes not shown in diff?

Tags: entities, nodes

I installed the Diff module so see the changes to node revisions. Works fine, but when I change an entity reference field the diff of that field is not shown. What could I be missing? From everything I've see the modules should integrate with each other. Diff 7.x-3.2 and Entityreference 7.x-1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that the fields were set to hidden in Mange Display *default* display setting. Set to Label and it works.